# PowerShell Get-ADUser Filter manager empty

Tags: powershell, syntax, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to retrieve all the users that have no manager assigned to them in the active directory. Whatever I try, it always spits out errors.

**Works fine:**

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {-not(lastLogonTimeStamp -like "*")} -Properties * -SearchBase "xxx"
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {-not(manager -like "*")} -Properties * -SearchBase "xxx"
Get-ADUser -Filter {manager -ne "*"} -Properties * -SearchBase "xxx 
Get-ADUser -Filter {manager -eq $null} -Properties * -SearchBase "xxx
Get-ADUser -Filter {manager -notlike '*'} -Properties * -SearchBase "xxx
```

Without using the `where`clause, does anyone have an idea about the correct syntax?

**Workaround:**

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "xxx" -Filter * -Properties * | where {$_.manager -eq $null}
```

Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-LDAPFilter` switch:

```powershell
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!manager=*)" -Properties *
```

Comment: Awesome! And when doing `Measure-Command` it appears to be also 3 times faster than with the `where` clause. Thanks Raf :)

Comment: Filtering at the source will ALWAYS be much faster. Raf's solution return an array of users with an empty manager field from the start, using Where-Object will mean that it needs to first retrieve every single user and then cycle through them to figure out which have an empty manager field.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code, if in addition you need to get only enabled accounts missing the manager field and test it with a 1000 user population.  You use the searchbase if you want to speed up the search but not necessary if you have time.  :)

```
$results =Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -ResultSetSize 1000 | where {$_.manager -eq $null -and $_.enabled -eq $True} |select samaccountname, mail, manager, enabled
$results
```